# Powershell function "if test-connection" true

Tags: powershell, shell

Heyy guys,

i have a powershell script which is working fine but i want to expand it with another line. Here is what i have.

```
$Path = "\\xyz\trigger1.txt"
$Path2 = "$env:userprofile\xyz\trigger2.txt"

if ((Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -and (-not(Test-Path $Path2 -PathType Leaf))){ 



if((get-process "XXX" -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null)
{ 
    "not Running"
    copy-item "\\xyz\xyz\*" "$env:userprofile\def\" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    start-sleep -s 5
     
}
else
{
    "running"
    stop-process -name "XXX" -force
    start-sleep -s 5
    copy-item "\\xyz\xyz\*" "$env:userprofile\def\" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    start-sleep -s 5
     
}
}
else
{

start-sleep -s 5
}
```

Now i want to expand that script with a function, that checks at first, if a server is available. if its not, it should use a permant test-connection until its available. When the server is available, the script should keep going.

Comment: if you need to do this with _many_ systems, then you may want to run it in parallel via `Invoke-Command`. that will accept a list of target systems, a scriptblock, any needed account info ... and run the code _on the target systems_. this gives you parallelization AND offloads the work to the target. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Do
{
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $computerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable pingError | Out-Null
    $pingError = $pingError | Where-Object { $_.CategoryInfo.Category -Eq 'ResourceUnavailable' }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
While($pingError -Ne $Null)
```

The script will go out of this loop only when no error of type ResourceUnavailable occurs.

Comment: so just define variable for the computername and paste it in front of my script?

Comment: Yes. $computerName being the server name. But this will loop indefinitely if $computerName never replies to pings.

Answer (score 0):

Using Test-Connection with the -Quiet option will return true or false:

```
Test-Connection $MachineName -Count 1 -Quiet
```